# ScrollView on top of a ZStack

Tags: swiftui

Considering the following example:

```
ZStack{
    VStack{
        ForEach(0..100) { elem in
            Button(action: {"do something..."}, label: Text("\(elem)"))
        }
    }

    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<100) { elem in 
            Text("\(elem)")
        }    
    }
}
```

When I put a `ScrollView` on top of the buttons the `ScrollView` is not scrollable anymore. Only at the positions where no button is under the `ScrollView`. Is it possible to "deactivate" underlying ZStack-layers? I've tried `.disable()` but this was not helpful.
This is not a real world example. The `ScrollView` will appear as a pop up and therefore I need to know how to solve this use case.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Comment: @Erik: your question is unclear, but I can tell where is the issue, your VStack is bigger than screen, and that makes ScrollView not working! if you use smaller range in your VStack it would scroll!

Answer (score 0):

Just give the scroll View some Height. Otherwise the height of scrollView becomes larger then of the screen, having all the elements inside so it becomes un-scrollable, because there is nothing to scroll.

```
struct ContentView: View { 
let fullHeight : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<100) { elem in
                Button(action: {
                        let _ = print("do something...")
                }, label:{ Text("Buttons \(elem)")  }
                )
            }
        }
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<100) { elem in
                Text("\(elem)")
            }
        } .frame( height: fullHeight , alignment: .center)
    }
       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple solution:

```
ZStack{
    VStack{
        ForEach(0..100) { elem in
            Button(action: {"do something..."}, label: Text("\(elem)"))
        }
    }

    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<100) { elem in 
            Text("\(elem)")
        }    
    }
    .zIndex(1) // <<<<<------ solution
}
```